# Why do healpix "alm" routines return arrays l and m of the same length?

Tags: python, math, healpy

From what I remember of my quantum physics and university maths, for every mode `l`, there exists `m = l-1, l, l+1`. Why do healpix (in my case, specifically [healpy](http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) spherical harmonic routines, e.g. `healpy.sphtfunc.alm2map`, return arrays of `l` and `m` that are the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to `map2alm`.

Let's check an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
m = np.arange(12) # define a map
lmax = 2
alm = hp.map2alm(m, lmax=lmax) # spherical armonic transform
print(alm)
[  1.94198894e+01 +0.00000000e+00j  -1.22780488e+01 +0.00000000e+00j
  -3.22928935e-01 +0.00000000e+00j   6.85510448e-01 -2.13069336e+00j
   4.66136940e-16 +6.36302781e-18j  -6.44680479e-01 +1.16180552e+00j]
print(alm.shape)
(6,)
```

So `alm` is actually a 1D vector.

How is `alm` indexed?

```py
l, m = hp.Alm.getlm(lmax=lmax)
print(l)
[0 1 2 1 2 2]
print(m)
[0 0 0 1 1 2]
```

So, for `l = 2`, `m` is `[0, 1, 2]`.

You can find out more about `HEALPix` in the `HEALPix` primer: http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/pdf/intro.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The missing bits from Andrea Zonca's answer:

- For every mode `l` the range of `m` is actually from `-l` to `+l` (so `2l+1` of them). But we are dealing with real signals, for which the `alm` for opposite `m` are complex conjugates, so `HEALPix` does not store the `alm` values for `m<0` (so only `l+1` of them).
- In the `alm` array returned by `hp.map2alm`, Andrea's example shows that the ordering is by increasing `m` then increasing `l`. You don't need to do the bookkeeping, to know the index of `(l≥0,m≥0)` in the array `alm` you can use the convenience function `hp.Alm.getidx(lmax,l,m)`, where `lmax = hp.Alm.getlmax(len(alm))`.